# Glassfish server cache not getting updated when using @XmlAdapter?

Tags: java, jpa, jaxb, glassfish, jersey

I've stumbled upon a strange problem using a @XmlAdapter. Let me try to sketch the situation:

At the server side I have a class Cows:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class Cows implements Serializable {
    ...a bunch of cow properties like ID, name, ...

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "sampless")
    @XmlElement(name = "samples") 
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "cowId")
    private List<Samples> samplesList;

    ...a bunch of getters & setters...
}
```

I have a class Samples:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class Samples implements Serializable {
    ...a bunch of samples properties like ID, cellcount, ...

    @JoinColumn(name = "cow_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(CowsAdapter.class)
    private Cows cowId;
}
```

CowsAdapter class:

```
public class CowsAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Cows, Cows> {
    @Override
    public Cows unmarshal(Cows v) throws Exception {
        return v;
    }
    @Override
    public Cows marshal(Cows v) throws Exception {
        return null;
    }
}
```

I include a list of samples when a Cow object is requested by the client as shown above.

Now, at client side, when I try to add a new Sample for a Cow, it marshals correctcly into a xml string (including the Cow object) which is send to the webservice. A new entry is correctly added to the database.

However, when I request the same Cow again (with the samplesList included), the new Sample is not added althou it is in the database? When I restart the glassfish instance, it shows.. Why is this and should I use another approach to avoid this?

Edit: same behaviour happens when deleting samples. It gets deleted from the database but is still included in the response of a Cow request. This has something to do with the cache of glassfish?

Edit2: I found some kind of solution for this. I changed the findById method as follows:

```
@GET
@Path("cow/{id}")
@Produces({"application/xml"})
public Cows findById(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    //Cows cow = super.find(id);
    final Query qry = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Cows.findById", Cows.class);
    qry.setParameter("id", id);
    qry.setHint("javax.persistence.cache.storeMode", "REFRESH");

    Cows cow = (Cows) qry.getSingleResult();
    return cow;
}
```

However, could someone let me know if this is the best approach?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabled the Glassfish cache for now by adding a property  to persistence.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain both sides of a relationship.  If you create a new Sample you need to add it to its Cow's samples.

See,
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Object_corruption.2C_one_side_of_the_relationship_is_not_updated_after_updating_the_other_side